# What are early examples of the rare notational convention to make the sign of the real number represented by a letter depend on the typography?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, notation, mathematical-logic

**Question.**

What early *published* or *citably attested* examples (preferably in the mathematical literature) can you give of the following convention?

Let $\mathbb{S}$ denote some nonempty subset of some specified alphabet $\mathbb{A}$.

Then the convention is made that

- in any formula, any letter from $\mathbb{S}$ must be interpreted to a *strictly negative* real number (i.e. $<0$), while any letter from $\mathbb{A}\setminus \mathbb{S}$ must be interpreted to a *strictly positive* real number (i.e. $>0$).

**Remarks.**

- An example is $\mathbb{A}:=$Latin alphabet, $\mathbb{S}:=$consonants.

  Then, for example,

  $\mathrm{for}\ \mathrm{all}\ a,\mathrm{for}\ \mathrm{all}\ z,\qquad a\cdot z < 0\qquad (\mathrm{sen})$

  is a true sentence,

  while, needless to say, with the usual convention of indifference to the typographical shape of variable symbols, (sen) is false, since *without the convention* there are both $(a,z)$ with $a\cdot z<0$ and $(a,z)$ with $a\cdot z>0$.
- This is a ***rare*** convention, yet it *exists* in the mathematical literature.

It can make formulas more concise.

To give a *toy example* (this is *not* the application in the published article which made me ask this question): this convention is useful to more concisely realize the idea of

- 'necessarily false formula'
- 'possibly yet not necessarily true formula'.

Needless to say, a formula (in the model-theoretic sense) is *never* true or false, only after interpretation via a *specified satisfaction-relation*.

Definition:  a 'necessarily false formula'$:=$shorthand for the longer term 'necessarily false formula over a specified signature $\Sigma$, and w.r.t. a specified satisfaction relation $\vDash$, and w.r.t. a specified form-formula $\Phi$' (in the usual sense of model theory)$:=$shorthand for quadruple ($\varphi,\Phi,\Sigma,\vDash$) wherein $\Sigma$ is a signature, $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ are formulas over $\Sigma$, $\vDash$ is a satisfaction relation for formulas over $\Sigma$ (note that this implies that there is a specified structure $\mathfrak{R}$ in the background), such that $\varphi$ is obtained from $\Phi$ by substitution of variables (in the usual technical sense, where as usual *substitution of variables is indifferent to sorts of variables; you may substitute any sort of variable for any other*), and $\neg\ (\mathfrak{R}\vDash \varphi[\alpha])$ for every variable assignment $\mathfrak{\alpha}$ (variable assignment maps must respect sorts of variables).

For the example, if the above convention is in force, then

- $a<z$ is a 'necessarily false formula' w.r.t. the form-formula $x<y$, the signature $<,\mathrm{negvar},\mathrm{posvar}$ and the (standard satisfaction relation $\vDash$ of) the structure $(\mathbb{R},<)$,
- $z<a$ is a 'possibly yet not necessarily true' formula w.r.t. the form-formula $x<y$, the signature $<,\mathrm{negvar},\mathrm{posvar}$ and the (standard satisfaction relation $\vDash$ of) the structure $(\mathbb{R},<)$,

Now where's the *difference* to the usual situation in which variables are not *sorted*? In this situation, *it is impossible to write a 'necessarily false formula' of the form '$x<y$' with $x,y$ arbitrary variables*.

The whole question is related to what, in particular in categorical logic, are called *sorted signatures*. In a sense, here, the consonants have sort 'strictly negative real number' and the non-consonants have sort 'strictly positive real number'.

- Example citations I will not give, since I am hoping for examples far older than the one I could give.

Comment: I have never seen this. There is a common convention of having letters from the middle of the alphabet represent integers and from the end represent arbitrary reals, or have Greek letters from the beginning of the alphabet represent (typically infinite) ordinals and those from the middle represent infinite cardinals (and $\omega $ having a specific meaning).

Comment: Your framework is so bizarre (I see no purpose for such a letter convention and have never heard of it before) that I do not find your reason to *refuse* to give even a single historical example of it compelling. Please show us at least one example. Then you can ask if anyone knows an earlier instance instead of hiding examples from us. I am almost tempted to suspect, since you give no example, that you are making this up and there are no examples.

Comment: Dear @KCd: again, in view of the above discussion it seems not right to single out an example here. If someone else gives one, in particular a more 'historical' one than the one I am looking at, I will appreciate it, since I find this notational convention, and innovative notation in general, interesting and useful. Thanks again for confirming that this seems to be rare.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: no, it is not me that is the author. As to Sanskrit: hazard. I seriously am interested in seeing other examples of this convention being put to use, and got carried away a bit too much when trying to write a complete question-description, trying to dot every i, as they say, and started to think of alphabets.

Comment: Dear @KCd: thanks for your comment, which in particular agrees with the view, also present in the title of the question, that this a rare convention. It surprises and hurtsme a little that you are "almost tempted to suspect [...] that [I am] making this up." Why should I? And isn't this self-contradictory: is this is so rare as we seem to agree it is, isn't it unlikely that I made this up out of thin air and asked the above question? I have a published paper using this convention before me; the author is active, which is why I find it impossible to comply with your request.

Comment: Then I find your refusal to provide an example as defeating the presumed goal of encouraging others to take an interest in your question.  If the instructor in a course introduces an abstract definition and then doesn't give any example of it even after the students ask for one, I don't think the instructor is helping the class care about the concept.

Comment: "*A mathematical convention is a fact, name, notation, or usage which is generally agreed upon by mathematicians*". If you are reluctant to give specific sources could you at least point to an area or a group of mathematicians that employ this convention? It might help people find what you are looking for.

Comment: I am voting to close this as its current formulstion is not serious. There are other sites for puzzles and games.

Comment: Dear @AndrésE.Caicedo: the formulation of the OP was changed to what I think is an improvement. I agree that there "are other sites for puzzles and games.", yet do neither think that *this* is a puzzle nor a game. Of course, 'puzzle' and 'game' are rather undefined. As for 'puzzle': this question does not have a unique isolated solution, as many puzzles have, rather it is related to the useful general method of employing *sorted signatures*. Again, thanks for commenting on the question.

Comment: Dear @KCd: thanks for the comment containing "presumed goal". Thinking about it, I think that a reason for the "Example citations I will not give" in the OP was maybe too rigidly trying to adhere to some format 'question statement, remarks, and within the remarks say something on examples' which led me to even say that the motivating example will not be given. Think of it like someone ineptly clinging to the 'introduction,body,conclusion' format for English composition. I regret that the only published example I know I feel impossible to give. If I find a sufficiently historical example, [...]

Comment: [...] then I will add it here. Moreover, I am working on a non-toy example involving some non-trivial number-theory. *That* example will be made-up by me, while the literature example motivating the question exists in the literature, yet is simply too recent to be appropriate to be singled out here. Thanks again for the feedback. @KCd

Comment: Dear @Conifold: re " could you at least point to an area or a group of mathematicians that employ this convention": I am afraid this would bias the question; it seems to me that this would lower the chances of finding a historical example. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about biasing at this point since currently the most likely outcome is to have no examples proposed at all. Moreover, even if biasing made more recent examples more likely to be proposed it would still improve the chances of finding a historical example because chains of transmission can usually be followed back from them.

Comment: I've been reading mathematics fairly indiscriminately :) for several decades, and have not seen a single instance of this in any "field" of mathematics. I'd be curious to hear of any two examples, that is, more than a single author.

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely clear to me what you mean... Would this be an example?

In the FORTRAN programming language (1957)$^1$, variables beginning with letters `I,J,K,L,M,N` represent integers, and other variables represent floating point values.

$^1$ Backus, J. W.; H. Stern, I. Ziller, R. A. Hughes, R. Nutt, R. J. Beeber, S. Best, R. Goldberg, L. M. Haibt, H. L. Herrick, R. A. Nelson, D. Sayre, P. B. Sheridan (1957). "The FORTRAN Automatic Coding System". Western joint computer conference: Techniques for reliability. Los Angeles, California

Comment: Dear @Gerald Edgar: thanks for pointing out. Well, obviously in the example you give the *signs are not mentioned*, and the reference you give does not critically use this convention (I suppose), in the sense of writing sentences which would be false without it. So this is not an example.

Comment: If you have a question for the user, it should be in a comment, not in an answer.